# Dynamic 3D models on the web

Tags: solidworks

I'm a software developed posed with a task of rendering a 3D model on the web/mobile app while also being able to allow end-users to change a text embedded in the model.

For example, a web page would contain a simple text input form field and whatever goes in there should be automatically rendered within the model.

We are currently using different tools to create models - Solidworks, Rhino, Keyshot, and Zbrush.

So far I found that KeyShotWeb allows me to render a model and change some aspects of it - but not edit text.

I'm also open to other 3D modeling programs that might allow me to achieve this.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling they sent you up the creek without a paddle.

1. Define who is making the rendering process, the user's device or the server.
2. If the answer is the user's device you need to use a simple render engine like WebGL, OpenGL or a JavaScript-based one like three.js.
3. If you want to render on the server you can use a more powerful render engine, there are several open-source. The obvious choice is Blender's Eevee or Cycles, but there are several render engines. LuxRender, Yafaray, Appleseed, the grandaddy POV-ray, etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_3D_rendering_software
4. You could also simply use a game engine like Unity, or a free one like Ogre. Even the Doom 3 engine seems to be GPL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines
5. One thing you need to consider is making a layered render. When you render a text just render that and overlay it to a pre-rendered object.

Comment: Keyshot is actually a really highend rendering engine.

Comment: Thank you @Rafael, the rendering process should be made on the user's device. I'll check which of the tools we currently use has the ability to export to any of the web engines and keep this thread updated. Thanks again!

Comment: Have a look at babylonJS.